# registering custom JSON marshallers

Tags: json, rest, grails

In my Grails 2.5.0 app, I use a bunch of custom JSON marshallers to tightly control the JSON format that is returned by my REST endpoints. Currently I register these marshallers in a service like so

```
class MarshallerRegistrarService {

    static transactional = false

    LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator

    // a combination of eager bean initialization and @PostConstruct 
    // ensures that the marshallers are registered when the app (or 
    // a test thereof) starts
    boolean lazyInit = false

    @PostConstruct
    void registerMarshallers() {

        // a collection of Enums that can be rendered to JSON
        def jsonEnums = [PaymentFrequency, Operation]

        jsonEnums.each { Class enumType ->
            JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(enumType) { Enum enumValue ->
                enumValue.toString()
            }
        }

        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(TimelineItem) { TimelineItem timelineItem ->
            def domainInstance = timelineItem.item

            return [
                    date: timelineItem.date,
                    type: domainInstance.class.simpleName,
                    item: [id: domainInstance.id],
                    link: grailsLinkGenerator.link(absolute: true, mapping: 'downloadForm', params: [apiVersion: 'v1', id: domainInstance.id])
            ]    
        }

        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {

            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')
            def formatted = it?.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", tz)
            return formatted
        }

        // more marshallers registered here (much more!)
    }
}
```

One of the reasons for this approach is that I can access spring beans (e.g. `grailsLinkGenerator`) while rendering JSON.

However a couple of downsides are:

- defining and registering the marshallers within the body of a method makes them difficult to test
- the `registerMarshallers` method quickly gets out-of-control as the number of marshallers grows

I'd prefer to define each marshaller within it's own class and register it as a Spring bean in `resources.groovy`, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do it :-)
Make all your marshallers `@Component` and register them with JSON during or after instantiation. Another approach would be to make them `@Component` and stamp them with an interface or base class and register them during bootstrap/plugin init like this:

```
ctx.getBeansOfType(MarshallerBase).each { name, bean ->
   bean.registerMarshallers()
}
```

assuming each marshaller implements the `registerMarshallers()` method.
There's many more approaches to it though.

Comment: Don't you have to configure somewhere which packages Grails should search for beans annotated `@Component`

Comment: That happens for all classes under `src/groovy`. See http://mrhaki.blogspot.cz/2013/02/grails-goodness-injecting-grails.html.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading that mrhaki page wrongly, but it seems to suggest you need to set `grails.spring.bean.packages` in `Config.groovy`

Comment: You're right! That's exactly what's in my config file!